# How do you make a button automatically press without user interaction in Swift Cocoa

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa, button

This sounds like a weird question, but I am using Swift 2.0 and Xcode to create a cocoa app, and I have a popover linked to an invisible button. I wan't to activate it so it pops up after the user has been on the page for a little while. I have a timer set, but I can't figure out the code to get the button to actually activate at that time, so that the popover will show. I am using a button so I can have an access spot for the popover to show at.

Right now, if you click the (invisible) button, everything shows perfectly. However, I need the click to activate programmatically. I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: you can enable and disable buttons with the .enabled property

Comment: I want the button to actually be pressed - like simulate someone clicking it, not just appear/work or disappear/not work.

Comment: If you have a timer, why not just use timer directly call the function that show the popover? the same function that attached to the button. So the function can either be accessed by pressing the button or automatically called by the timer when time is enough.

Comment: What would I link the popover to? I need it to show at a specific location, that is why I am using the button. The popover just shows above the button. Are you saying to just use a new view controller directly? How would I get it linked to a certain spot, and activate it? I am new to Swift/Xcode.

Comment: You don't need a button to show popover, you can use a uiview, a point or a cgrect if I remember correctly. I've done similar thing, just search the documentation. Because the only thing the popover needs is a point where it pops out. So that doesn't need to be a button. If you need to press the button to show the popover, that's another story

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice! - This works if you want to make the button click itself - 
   
`@IBOutlet var randomButton: NSButton!
   
            randomButton.performClick(nil)`  - You can't make it an action, you need to make it an outlet.